# Storing configuration data in a global variable on application startup

Tags: python

I've never used a global variable in one of my programs(of which there are few) before, is this a fair use of one?

Currently, I have several classes calling a function to grab the data they require from a .yaml file stored in the user home folder. Each class constructs the full path of where the .yaml file should be using two vars; os.path.expanduser("~") and the default filename. This I feel, is messy.

The code below is a simple example of my actual program:

hub.py(Context manager instantiated on startup by main.py):

```
class Hub:

    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = "config_data.yaml"
        self.filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), self.filename)


    def __enter__(self):
        global config_data

        with open(self.filepath) as f:
            config_data = yaml.load(f)

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, value, traceback):
        pass

with Hub() as hub:
    pass
```

Example use:

```
from hub import config_data

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pricing_params = config_data["pricing"]
```

Comment: What is `hub` and what is `config_data`? The more code you add, the more we'll be able to help you. It may also be good in some cases, but not others. Currently I'm on the fence on whether this should be global or not, and more code would make me go on either side.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether or not this is a good use of global variables, it is a poor use of a `class`.

Your `hub.py` could look like this and function exactly the same (you could still import `config_data` from it):

```
import os
import yaml

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "config_data.yaml")
with open(file_path) as f:
    config_data = yaml.load(f)
```

And now that it is obvious that this does not actually do a lot, I would make this a function and put this in your actual script (or maybe a utils script, if you have many more utilities like that):

file `utils.py`:

```
import yaml

def get_config(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return yaml.load(f)
```

file `bot.py`:

```
import os
from utils import get_config


FILE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "config_data.yaml")
CONFIG_DATA = get_config(FILE_PATH)

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pricing_params = CONFIG_DATA["pricing"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = Bot()
```